# R shinyDashboard: Add more than the 5 ValidStatus / More colors needed

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

When formatting boxes in shinyDashboard one has to use the status argument. However, only five valid statuses are eligible (?validStatuses, also: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html). I found out how to change these predefined colors, but I need more than five colors and therefore need to add additional statuses. 
Is there a way to add valid statuses to the existing five?

Thanks

Comment: This one is related/maybe even duplicate. Please test it yourself, as you haven't provided any code of yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016826/change-color-in-shinydashboard

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I know how to overwrite the color of an instance. The problem is that there are only 5 instances to change (see ?validStatuses). there I need more than those 5.